# Drop by/in to a large place

Tags: phrase-usage

Drop by/in is usually used for a casual visit to small places like someone's office or house, but what about a larger locale? For example, can you say...?

> Next time you drop by Toronto, please call me.

What alternatives do you suggest?

Comment: Dear Kaimei, voting on this site is typically utterly irrational. The fact your question was downvoted means nothing -- just so you know.

Answer (score 2):

This is an excellent and subtle question.

(1) you definitely **can** say "next time you drop by Toronto" - that's a common formulation for cities.

(2) The difference between in/by tends to be rather literal: please consider on the one hand an office (imagine a small office, perhaps a real estate office, with two staff).  Consider on the other hand a petrol station (where you bring your car to fill the tank).  It would, perhaps, be less natural to say "drop in to" a petrol station (since you don't, really, go "in" to it ... you're more "at" it or "beside" it).  On the other hand you literally go "in" to an office.

There are many similar examples: it's less meaningful to drop "in" to a sports field (for example), but you very much come "in" to a house.

(3) There is a very slight sense, I would say, that "by" is less "demanding socially".  Say you have been dating someone only once or twice. You might say "drop by my house" .. you're merely "coming by", "saying hello while passing".  Drop "in" to my house is more commitment, you're literally coming physically in, it's going to be a longer visit; so for example "come by for a coffee" versus "come in for dinner"

once again, in answer to your overall question, "Can by/in be used for physically large things like cities ..." the answer is very much **yes**.

Note that "Next time you're in Toronto..." is the most common formulation.

there are very few alternatives, and they are specific: such as "next time you're visiting Toronto..." or "next time you're working in Toronto..." or "next time you find yourself in Toronto" (which is really just "in" again) or "next time you fly in to Toronto..." (again, really just "in").

In a sense, "in" is the correct, perhaps only, formulation here (and "by" is also fine, even though it can seem a bit illogical for a physically "large" thing). If you do use "by" for a large city, there's a sense in which you're being perhaps almost humorously dismissive of the act (as in point 3 above): so, if your friend is a real jet-setter, always travelling, you might particularly say "drop by Toronto".  To make an extreme, pretty much humorous version of that: "Next time you drop by Asia, be sure to visit me in Asakusa!" or "Next time you drop by Europe, be sure to see the musée d'Orsay!"

Answer (score 0):

I'd say

> Next time you're in Toronto, look me up.